# How can I install Google Chrome and Talk to a non-default location?

Tags: google-chrome, google-talk

I'm trying to install Google Chrome and Google Talk to a non-default location. How can I do this? My Googling suggested that the Pack installer can do it, but for me it didn't give any such functionality.  I only have a tiny SSD and need to keep everything possible off the main drive, and I re-install Windows frequently and don't wish to have to re-download. In my previous installation Chrome ate up several hundred MB (!) and it really needs to go not on my SSD.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Google pack installer will do this.

Don't click start though.  There is a customize button.

Comment: Google Pack has been discontinued, though :(

Comment: Yet the multiuser installer for Chrome and Talk, which Google Pack used, is still there.  Just Google multi user install.

Answer (score 2):

One cannot install Google Chrome or Talk to a non-default location, but one can move it afterwards. The disadvantage of this is that you will need to do this operation again when you reinstall your operating system (apropos, why do you reinstall it frequently?).

The mechanism is explained in [this answer](http://www.google.com/support/forum/p/Chrome/thread?tid=189c30af17946e9d&fid=189c30af17946e9d00046f7e5446ecfe&hl=en) of the thread "How can I install Chrome on a different drive than C:". It basically involves moving the Chrome directory elsewhere and replacing it with a [junction](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NTFS_junction_point) (symbolic link) that will point to the new directory and fool Chrome into thinking that it is still in its old place. This uses the free [sysinternals Junction](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896768.aspx).

For example :

```
junction.exe "C:\Users\Bapa\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome" "D:\Data\temp\chrome"
```

If you wish for a free product that does the work for you, use [Steam Mover](http://www.traynier.com/software/steammover),
originally designed to help hardcore gamers move their downloaded games to other drives,
but works well with other applications too.

See this lifehacker article :
[Steam Mover Relocates Applications to Free Up Space on Your Primary Drive](http://lifehacker.com/5626931/steam-mover-relocates-applications-to-free-up-space-on-your-primary-drive).

[EDIT}

Another solution is to use [Google Chrome Portable](http://portableapps.com/apps/internet/google_chrome_portable) : It's packaged as a portable app, so you can take your browsing experience with you. See also [Portable Google Talk](http://portableapps.com/node/835).

Comment: No, I don't reinstall frequently. On the university computers, I have a small personal network share; I'd like to install Chrome there.

Comment: I wonder what will happen if you will create the junction **before** you install Google Chrome, to fool it into thinking that its folder(s) already exist.

Comment: Unfortunately, I lack admin powers here to do that. Sure, I could reinstall Chrome every single time I sit down here and use sync to get by, but it takes a while. :)

Comment: Only an administrator can create symbolic links, so this is out. See my edit above for another solution.

Comment: I'm using Chrome Portable right now, but it has two major problems. It can't install any extensions (as the sandbox requires a local disk) and it won't autoupdate, but I guess it's as close as it gets. I guess I just can't be happy :)

Comment: According to [this article](http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/20006/run-portable-chrome-from-your-flash-drive-on-any-windows-machine/), extensions should be installable, and updating is done non-automatically by running Updater.exe in the PortableGoogleChrome folder.

Comment: They aren't, Chrome insists that sandboxing needs to happen inside your profile folder and refuses to work on remote shares, junctions and other trickery.